# How to show option menu in android 4.2

Tags: android, menuitem

I am trying to create menu option in my test application.

I am able to see the menu when I set the theme in manifest to just default (The menu shows up in the top). If I set the theme in manifest to NoTitleBar. I can't see the menu option?

I want to get the menu when I set theme "NoTitleBar" in manifest.

How to fix it?

Below are things that I have used in my test application:

with Manifest:

```
  <uses-sdk
      android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.ssn.menuoptions.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

And

Menu.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:id="@+id/menu_preferences"
      android:title="Preferences" /> 
 </menu>
```

Java file:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Is it possible to get something like this:

[image: file:///C:/Users/Koushik/Downloads/SahayaPictures/fHEQ8.png]

How do I make menu to show up down?

Thanks!

Comment: On devices with a menu button (like the Galaxy S2) it will show up when you press the menu button. On other devices it's in the title bar. Why are you removing the title bar if you have a menu?

Comment: I have seen couple of menu down.. Like the image shown in my question. How is it done?

Comment: Also Facebook app shows menu in the bottom for 4.2.

Answer (score 2):

Add following code below Activity.setContentView();

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
    // set option menu if has no hardware menu key
    boolean hasMenu = ViewConfiguration.get(this).hasPermanentMenuKey();
    if(!hasMenu){
        //getWindow().setFlags(0x08000000, 0x08000000);
        try {
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.class.getField("FLAG_NEEDS_MENU_KEY").getInt(null));
          }
          catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            // Ignore since this field won't exist in most versions of Android
          }
          catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            Log.w("Optionmenus", "Could not access FLAG_NEEDS_MENU_KEY in addLegacyOverflowButton()", e);
          }
    }
```

Comment: hasPermanentMenuKey() is not found as a method. This was brought in with API 22.

Comment: @AndrewS For me the documentation in my IDE says it was in 14. The workaround is to add a version check first.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want an action bar in your app, then you can just set up a button with this handler:

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) { openOptionsMenu(); }
});
```

Now `myButton` works like the menu key.  This is an easy way to migrate a fullscreen app to 4.x, though longer term a more elegant solution should be sought.

Answer (score 0):

Using the notitlebar theme removes the actionbar where the menu button is. You'd probably have to make a custom theme to have your menu in it.
If you're not doing anything about it, you can always at least use this attribute: `android:showAsAction="Never"` so that users with phones that have a menu button can pop up the menu with their button.

Comment: Where do I show this: android:showAsAction="Never"? In Manifest or Menu.xml?

Comment: In the menu.xml, in your <item /> tag.

Comment: I have seen couple of menu down.. Like the image shown in my question. How is it done?

Comment: If I refer to [this post](http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html), it should show up, provided you don't use actionbar (which is the case here...)

Try to replace the theme by `"@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar"`

Comment: Didn't work. It is looking Api 11 and After change it is still the same?

Comment: For. e.g SMS-backup has this menu coming up in the bottom and in the top.

Answer (score 0):

Add in Android Manifest android:targetSdkVersion="10"

```
<uses-sdk
    android:targetSdkVersion="10" />
```