# FEATURE_NO_TITLE also removes menu

Tags: android, android-layout

I created a custom menu bar. Nothing complicated just a LinearLayout which holds six ImageButtons because the default Android title menu was too inconsistent for my app. With inconsistent I mean that the count of Buttons displayed on top changed from device to device.
To hide the android title bar I set the following in styles.xml

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

In my menu.xml I also set the “showAsAction” param to “never”

```
   <item
    android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/my_menu_settings"/>
```

Everything worked fine. I tested my app on:
- Asus Transformer tf300
- Samsung Galaxy Note 2
- Samsung Galaxy S 3
- Lg Optimus 4x Hd P880
- Samsung Galaxy Ace
- Multiple Emulators
- And some more...

But today I tested my App on my all new Sony Xperia Z1.
The problem there is that when I click the menu button (one of the three default android buttons -> return, home and menu) the menu isn't displayed.
The device returns to the app list. No menu is opened!

My question is:
Is there something wrong with my approach?
I just notized this behavior on my Xperia Z but I’m not sure if there is something completely wrong in my code and there are many more devices affected…

UPDATE:
I tried to override:onKeyUp and onKeyDown but these methods are not called. Also my breakpoint in my onCreateOptionsMenu is not hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the default Android title menu

It is called the action bar.

> With inconsistent I mean that the count of Buttons displayed on top changed from device to device.

That is by design. Android devices come in a wide range of screen sizes.

> Is there something wrong with my approach?

The overflow is a feature of the action bar. It *happens* to display even if you hide the action bar on some devices. However, particularly on devices that lack a dedicated MENU button, the overflow will not be available if you hide the action bar.

Hence, if you are going to hide the action bar, that's fine, but then you need to implement your own menu system, the way that games and other apps do.

Comment: Maybe "inconsistent" was the wrong word. It may sound a little negative. I don't want to blame this design, I know that it is implemented the way it is to support multiple screen sizes and put only buttons to title if there is space.
However, I have a forward and a back button in my menu and it is extremely inconvenient for the user if the forward button is on the top and the backward button is in bottom menu…
Can you point me to some resources how games implement this?
I updated my post and tried to catch the keydown/keyup event but this is not called.

Comment: @stefan: "However, I have a forward and a back button in my menu and it is extremely inconvenient for the user if the forward button is on the top and the backward button is in bottom menu" -- then set them to be `android:showAsAction="always"`, and allow other items to go into the overflow if needed. "Can you point me to some resources how games implement this?" -- AFAIK, that's built into the various game engines. "I updated my post and tried to catch the keydown/keyup event but this is not called" -- that will not help, as not all devices have a MENU key.

Comment: android:showAsAction="always" does not guarantee that two buttons are displayed. If there is just enough space for one button the other one will still be put to normal menu.
So it seems that I have to put some kind of trigger to my custom menu bar but this will break my design 
Is there a way to detect if the device has a menu button? So I can just show this button for specific devices.

Comment: ok.
Found lots of posts ...
ViewConfiguration.get(context).hasPermanentMenuKey()
seems to do the trick for me :)

Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 0):

Also found this:

```
 boolean hasMenu = ViewConfiguration.get(this).hasPermanentMenuKey();
        if(!hasMenu){
            //getWindow().setFlags(0x08000000, 0x08000000);
            try {
                     getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.class.getField("FLAG_NEEDS_MENU_KEY").getInt(null));
              }
              catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                // Ignore since this field won't exist in most versions of Android
              }
              catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                Log.w("Optionmenus", "Could not access FLAG_NEEDS_MENU_KEY in addLegacyOverflowButton()", e);
              }
        }
```

here:
[How to show option menu in android 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17667245/how-to-show-option-menu-in-android-4-2)

What do you think about that?
Seems to work on my Xperia.

UPDATE:
but not on Nexus 10, Asus Transformer TF 300.
Legacy menu was present but not working.

Final solution: -> created my own menu based on PopupWindow